# How can Dropbox API v2 work with dynamic redirect URL

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, dropbox, dropbox-api

Currently we are using Dropbox API v1 in our Ruby on Rails application and OAuth 1 because our app is locally hosted which can be accessed either via localhost or via IP address/servername(which can be anything).

Dropbox API v1 worked perfectly fine since it does not require redirect URL to be pre-registered. Now, We have to migrate to Dropbox API v2 but it does not support OAuth v1.

I there any way to use OAuth 2 with URLs which are not pre-registered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dropbox oauth2 dynamic return URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263120/dropbox-oauth2-dynamic-return-url)

Comment: @Greg, Thanks for redirecting. What i got from above thread mentioned is If I've to go with OAuth 2, Only way out for this is having a cloud service to which act as redirect URL and get actual one using "state" parameter?

Comment: Yes, though also note that you don't actually need to use a redirect URI at all. You can use the "code" flow without a redirect URI, in which case the user just needs to copy and paste the "authorization code" into your app manually during the OAuth 2 app authorization flow: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-authorize

Comment: Thanks @Greg for all the guidence and clarificaiton. As part of migrating our RoR app to API V2 , I've modifed existing [dropbox-sdk-ruby](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-ruby) also for most of the calls(connection, file and folder operations). Can i create a pull request on the same repository for the changes? or may be add to community sdk for ruby api v2?

Comment: Pull requests are welcome, but I can't promise if or when they'd be merged.